# NSTableView: Directly editing a textfield without highlighting the whole row

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

I have a `NSTextfield` in a `TableView`. The content mode is configured to `ViewBased`. So I have the type: `NSTableCellView`.

Example of my Table View:

[image]

My problem is that I can't edit until I have selected the line. However, I want to click on the text field independently of the line and edit directly without selecting the whole line.

Current solution: In the `Table View` I can currently set the highlight to `None` and then direct editing works, but I still want to be able to select the whole row when I click outside the `Textfield` in the row.

I would be very happy if someone could help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer - this is adapted after the nice answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13431004/1974224).

One possible approach is to subclass `NSTableView` and override `hitTest` in order to send the user interaction events directly to the text field instead of the cell view:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    let myPoint = superview!.convert(point, to: self)
    let column = self.column(at: myPoint)
    let row = self.row(at: myPoint)

    // if we find an editable text field at this point, we return it instead of the cell
    // this will prevent any cell reaction
    if row >= 0, column >= 0,
        let cell = view(atColumn: column, row: row, makeIfNecessary: false),
        let textField = cell.hitTest(convert(myPoint, to: cell.superview)) as? NSTextField,
        textField.isEditable {
        return textField
    } else {
        return super.hitTest(point)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved my problem! But now I have the problem that the clickable area of the textfield is further down than the visible area.

Comment: The `point` argument of `hitTest` is in the coordinate system of the view’s superview, not of the view itself. `column(at:)` and `row(at:)` expect a point in the coordinate system of the table view.

Comment: Yeah, exactly @Willeke you're right. Actually the convert function should solve the problem, but it doesn't work properly. So you have to click with the mouse a little bit further down, then it works. If I only use point, then I only get the first entry in the textfield. With the second entry it doesn't work at all. I think, if you modify the convert function or give an alternative, it should work fine.

Comment: @Willeke right, don't know how I missed that, thanks, updated the answer.

Comment: @Fatih updated the answer per Willeke's comment, run some tests with two textfield's per cell and the fields get selected as expected.